# Fix for flickering mouse in gedit on 15.04 when unsaved changes exist?

Tags: mouse, 15.04, gedit, cursor

Using ubuntu 15.04.

This only occurs in gedit. And it only occurs when there are unsaved changed in gedit. When there are unsaved changes, the mouse starts flickering. Here is a [video](https://vid.me/vKGV) of what it looks like. In the video I am moving the mouse around and it flickers in and out of view.

Is this a bug? Or is this something I can fix on my end? Gedit in 14.04 never did this.

Answer (score 1):

I experience this issue after I copy or paste some text in a new, unsaved tab, using the keyboard shortcuts ( Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V ).

Seems that by opening a dialog (for example the replace text dialog), fixes the issue.

It also happened that I had the issue on a tab and opening a dialog didn't help. I suspected that some other tab was causing the issue so I opened a dialog while on a different tab that was open and it fixed the issue.